# Escaping backslash in .gitconfig

Tags: git, escaping, git-config

I am attempting to set up a filter into my .gitconfig which replaces a string including backslashes with another string, also including backslashes.

```
clean = sed 's|foo|bar|g'
smudge = sed 's|foo|bar|g'
```

This example does work, as long as `foo` and `bar` do not include any `\`.

I am aware, that I should escape `\`, but I just can't get it to work properly.
Could somebody walk me through the process of getting this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, to escape a backslash, double it.  If `\x` becomes `x`, then `\\` becomes `\`.  This backslash interpretation "eats" backslashes, but not if they are prefixed by backslash.

That gets it past Git, where the shell eats it (interprets backslash followed by some other character as special), so if this command is fed to a shell, double it again.  Now one backslash in the final result is represented by *four* in the input.

If the shell passes it to a command like `sed` that treats backslash specially, double it again.  Now one backslash is eight!

Should that command pass the string on to another command that does backslash interpretation, you would need to double it yet again, and so on.  For this reason, we have other quoting mechanisms in the shell (and in other languages): inside single quotes, backslash is no longer special (no longer eaten) so you can halve the number of backslashes required using single quotes.  (Compare with, e.g., "raw" strings in Python.)  For this particular case, though, eight backslashes is probably not that much worse than careful single-quoting and four backslashes.

Comment: That thorough explanation did the trick. Thanks a lot, I got it working!

Comment: This could be improved with an example for each case discussed.